# Como "subir" turmas no banco utilizando também confirm javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

Olá, tenho o seguinte código e preciso pegar a turma de um aluno no banco e, em caso afirmativo ao `confirm` no JS: "subir" sua turma.

Ex: O aluno é da 1A, aperto o botão para subir e ele precisa ir para a 2A (mas não será só de uma, ao apertar esse botão todos irão subir também).

O código da forma como está abaixo entra no `confirm` porém se clicado no `OK`, a página fica em branco pois não faz mas nada.

Entendo que possui falhas porém não consigo pensar em nada (sério, socorro ;-;) e gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar :v (isso dai é só a ideia do que preciso)

```js
<script>
    function up()
    {
        <?php
        include ('connection.php');
        
        $busca = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM turmas;");
        $busca->execute();
        
        $linha = $busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        if($linha['turma'].equals("1A"))
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE carterinha SET turma = '2A';";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            
            try
            {
                $stmt->execute();
                echo '
                    <script>
                        alert("Turmas upadas!");
                        location.replace("../../index.php");
                    </script>
                ';
            } catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo '
                    <script>
                        alert("Falha! Tente novamente!");
                        location.replace("../../index.php");
                    </script>
                ';   
            }
        }
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

```html
<?php
    echo '
        <script>
        if(confirm("Deseja realmente upar as turmas?")) 
        {
            up();
            alert("Turmas upadas!");
            location.replace("../../index.php");
        } else 
        {
            alert("Up turma cancelado");
            location.replace("../../index.php");
        }
        </script>
    ';
?>
```

Comment: Olá o java script fica na parte cliente, e o php no servidor não é possível misturar os dois assim é necessário enviar através de um post ou get para o servidor com um formulário ou via JavaScript e no servidor salvar os dados.

Comment: entendo... Alguma sugestão do que posso faze, ao menos em "subir" as turmas :v ou fazer esse confirm junto do php de alguma forma?

Comment: É que assim, pelo que vi você está iniciando agora né? se sim uma dica seria começar a estudar só o php com o html depois adiciona o java script seira mais simples de entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está equivocado quanto a forma de comunicação Javascript -> PHP. O **PHP** é interpretado no back-end (servidor), ou seja, nenhum código que você escreva em PHP vai para o front-end (cliente). Assim sendo você precisa fazer o **Javascript** realizar uma chamada ao servidor para que ele execute o script PHP que deseja. Essa chamada poderia ser em **AJAX** por exemplo, ou simplesmente redirecionar um usuário para a página PHP em que se encontra o script. Recomendo você estudar um pouco esse tema.

Mas vou te dar uma luz nesse seu caso. Você vai criar um arquivo separado, que vamos chamar de `up.php`, e vai colocar nele o trecho de código que faz o UPDATE que você deseja:

```
<?php
    include ('connection.php');

    $busca = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM turmas;");
    $busca->execute();

    $linha = $busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($linha['turma'].equals("1A"))
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE carterinha SET turma = '2A';";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        try
        {
            $stmt->execute();
            echo 'Turmas upadas!';
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Falha! Tente novamente!';   
        }
    }
?>
```

E agora vamos ter o arquivo principal, vamos chamá-lo de `index.php`, vamos colocar nele o HTML e o Javascript, que vai chamar o `up.php` para realizar o update que você deseja.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo chamada AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="realizarChamada()">Chamar o PHP no servidor</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function realizarChamada() {
            if(confirm("Deseja realmente upar as turmas?")) 
            {
                // Aqui vamos realizar a chamada AJAX que falei

                // Instancio um objeto da classe XMLHttpRequest
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                // Defino o que vou fazer com o retorno obtido do servidor
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        // Aqui estou pegando o texto que eu dei echo lá no servidor e colocando no alert
                        alert(this.responseText);
                   }
                };

                // Abro a conexão com o arquivo desejado
                xhttp.open("GET", "up.php", true);

                // Envio a requisição
                xhttp.send();
            } else {
                alert("Up turma cancelado");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Essa página tem um botão que ao clicar, vai executar a requisição AJAX GET no servidor.

Como disse recomendo pesquisar sobre o tema. Deixo um artigo simples a seguir para estudo: [Criando um cadastro com PHP, Ajax e jQuery](https://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-cadastro-com-php-ajax-e-jquery/28046)